# Drawing a logarithmic spiral in three axes in Python

Tags: python, math, matplotlib, spiral

I try to draw a logarithmic spiral in the form of a spring in three axes.
Using the parametric equations:

```
x=a*exp(b*th)*cos(th)
y=a*exp(b*th)*sin(th)
```

Using the code:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import exp,sin,cos
from pylab import *

mpl.rcParams['legend.fontsize'] = 10

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
n=100
a=0.5
b=0.20
th=np.linspace(0, 500, 10000)
x=a*exp(b*th)*cos(th)
y=a*exp(b*th)*sin(th)
ax.plot(x, y)
ax.legend()

plt.show()
```

I get:

[image]

However, I would like to stretch the spiral along the `Z axis` to get a result similar to the following, but using the logarithmic spiral as the basis:

[image]

How can you do it? How do you modify the function by adding a condition to the `Z axis`?

Comment: This is a mathematics function, not a programming question. The z coordinate is a function of the distance from the center. Your values are also very large with the `1e42`.

Comment: You don't have any `z` coordinate given to the plot...

Comment: Well, yes, I could add any `z` variable, but I have no idea what the relation between `x and y` variables should be.

Comment: linear over `th`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since 95% of the points of the spiral are condensed in a single point in the middle of the plot it would make sense to restrict the plotted range to something like

```
th=np.linspace(475, 500, 10000)
```

Then using a linear range of z values would directly give you the desired curve in the plot, by simply specifying that range in the plot function, `plot(x,y,z)`.

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.rcParams['legend.fontsize'] = 10

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

a=0.5
b=0.20
th=np.linspace(475, 500, 10000)
x=a*np.exp(b*th)*np.cos(th)
y=a*np.exp(b*th)*np.sin(th)
z = np.linspace(0,2, len(th))
ax.plot(x, y, z)
#ax.legend()

plt.show()
```

[image]

Note that I cleaned up the imports here. E.g. if you import `cos` from `math` but later import everything (`*`) from pylab into the namespace, the function `cos` that is used is the numpy `cos` function, not the one from math (the math cos function would not work here anyways). In general: don't use pylab at all.

Answer (score 4):

Which `z` to take it's a bit up to you. From the plot itself it's hard to say but my guess is that it's linear (the simplest option).

Taking your code and adding the `z` axis you can do something like this

```
import matplotlib as mpl
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import exp,sin,cos
from pylab import *

mpl.rcParams['legend.fontsize'] = 10

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
a=0.05
b=0.10
# took the liberty of reducing the max value for th 
# as it was giving you values of the order of e42
th=np.linspace(0, 50, 10000)  
x=a*exp(b*th)*cos(th)
y=a*exp(b*th)*sin(th)
z=np.linspace(0,2, 10000)  # creating the z array with the same length as th
ax.plot(x, y, z)  # adding z as an argument for the plot
ax.legend()

plt.show()
```

You can play with your `a` and `b` parameters to get the elliptical shape you want. You can also play with the definition of `z` to make it exponential, or logarithmic in growth.. or something else entirely.

BTW, your imports are a bit redundant and probably some funtions from one package are being shadowed by another package.